# Return a reference of a struct from a method

Tags: c++

I have a struct `A`.
I have a class `B`.

In my main function, I instantiate `B` and set the struct's `TEST` property to `"ABC"`.

I then create a local struct and pass it through as a reference `outA`.

Then when I try and set `TEST` property to be `"123"`, I expect that the original instance b's property would also be modified, but somewhere it seems to have made a copy of the struct.

How do i ensure that I am modifying the instance of `B`'s `A` struct?

https://onlinegdb.com/BJ0V4vR5V

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    std::string TEST;
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;

    void GetA(A& outA)
    {
        outA = a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    b->a.TEST = "ABC";

    A refToA;
    b->GetA(refToA);

    refToA.TEST = "123";

    cout << b->a.TEST;

    return 0;
}
```

The actual context of my problem is more in depth, but i think this is the issue i'm coming up against.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `A a = b->GetA();` makes a copy.  You need `A& a = b->GetA();` to have a reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Thank you so much. I realise my question didn't quite hit the mark. I've modified the text slightly to incorporate the actual issue i have. Thanks

Comment: You're still making a copy.  `refToA` is not a reference so it is it's own object and any changes made to it are isolated to it.

Comment: How do i make a reference though? The syntax of A& refToA doesn't seem to be correct as it needs initialisation. (I think the question here is in this case, what's the correct syntax for doing that). Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: You have to have `getA` return a reference and then use something like `A& refToA = b->GetA();`.  Alternatively, you can pass a reference to a pointer and make the pointer point to `a` like `void GetA(A*& outA) { outA = &a; } A* ptrToA; b->GetA(ptrToA);`

Comment: Oh! I did not know that. That's interesting. And i suppose assigning the value after that is a `(*ptrToA).TEST = "123"` (If so, what is that called? de-referenced pointer?)

Comment: Correct. It's called dereferencing the pointer.